# Powermail field in subject

Tags: field, typo3, subject, powermail

I want to have a field of powermail in the reciever subject. I tried inserting it by using "`Testmail 123 {testfield}`".
I gave this field the custom variable name `{testfield}`.
But I can't get it to work, even tried with `{uid82}` in the subject.

Anybody had this problem and knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try overwriting. I answered a (my own) question about how to overwrite the reciever-email with a field (dropdown) in the form.

You can find the TS for that here:

https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.txt#L146

See my solution for the reciever here:

[Send TYPO3 EXT:powermail mail to diffrent recievers depending on selection in a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158364/send-typo3-extpowermail-mail-to-diffrent-recievers-depending-on-selection-in-a/41158365#41158365)

After posting part of the question in slack-channel of powermail ext, Alex posted this solution:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.subject = COA
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.subject {
10 = TEXT
10.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|markername
10.noTrimWrap = |My subject with the value ||
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you? Then pls confirm this answer working.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from randomresult is correct. Nevertheless it should be possible to simply use a subject like:
"New mail from {firstname}"

Possible reasons why it did not work:
- Your field is of type array and not string
- Your HTML-Source is different to 
- An unknown bug in powermail. If so, please report it to forge.typo3.org